Using functions, for loops, conditionals and lists
I have already successfully wrote a program that:
a. Accepts the names and ages of three people.
b. Prints the name of the oldest person.
c. Prints the name of the youngest person.
d. Prints their age category:
• Teen: Ages 13–19
• Adult: Ages 20–64
• Senior: Ages 65 and above
Here is my code:
person1_name = input("First person's name: ")
person1_age = int(input("First person's age: "))
person2_name = input("Second person's name: ")
person2_age = int(input("Second person's age: "))
person3_name = input("Third person's name: ")
person3_age = int(input("Third person's age: "))     # Prompting user to enter all 3 names and ages

if person1_age > person2_age and person1_age > person3_age:
    oldest = person1_age
    print(person1_name + " is the oldest.")
elif person2_age > person1_age and person2_age > person3_age:
    oldest = person2_age
    print(person2_name + " is the oldest.")
elif person3_age > person1_age and person3_age > person2_age:
    oldest = person3_age
    print(person3_name + " is the oldest.")          # This block is comparing all 3 ages to see which integer is the largest, then using an if conditional to print a statement if the condition is true
    
if person1_age < person2_age and person1_age < person3_age:
    youngest = person1_age
    print(person1_name + " is the youngest.")
elif person2_age < person1_age and person2_age < person3_age:
    youngest = person2_age
    print(person2_name + " is the youngest.")
elif person3_age < person1_age and person3_age < person2_age:
    youngest = person3_age
    print(person3_name + " is the youngest.")       # This block is comparing all 3 ages to see which integer is the smallest, then using an if conditional to print a statement if the condition is true

if person1_age in range(13,20):
    age_category = "Teen"
    print(f"{person1_name} is a {age_category}.")
elif person1_age in range(20,65):
    age_category = "Adult"
    print(f"{person1_name} is an {age_category}.")
elif person1_age >= 65:
    age_category = "Senior"
    print(f"{person1_name} is a {age_category}.")
else:
    print(f"{person1_name} is not in a valid age category.")   # This block is comparing the person's age to a range of numbers that define an age category, and prints a statement using an if conditional if their age belongs to that age range

if person2_age in range(13,20):
    age_category = "Teen"
    print(f"{person2_name} is a {age_category}.")
elif person2_age in range(20,65):
    age_category = "Adult"
    print(f"{person2_name} is an {age_category}.")
elif person2_age >= 65:
    age_category = "Senior"
    print(f"{person2_name} is a {age_category}.")
else:
    print(f"{person2_name} is not in a valid age category.")   # Same as above block but for person2

if person3_age in range(13,20):
    age_category = "Teen"
    print(f"{person3_name} is a {age_category}.")
elif person3_age in range(20,65):
    age_category = "Adult"
    print(f"{person3_name} is an {age_category}.")
elif person3_age >= 65:
    age_category = "Senior"
    print(f"{person3_name} is a {age_category}.")
else:
    print(f"{person3_name} is not in a valid age category.")  # Same as above block but for person3

Now I need to do the same problem, but use functions, for loops, conditionals and lists.
I have been at this for hours and just cannot figure out what to do. This is what I've written so far:
names = []
ages = []
    
for x in range(0,3):
    names.append(input())
    ages.append(int(input()))

oldest = max(ages)
print(oldest)

youngest = min(ages)
print(youngest)
        
def age_category_function(age):
    for y in ages:
        if age > -1 and age < 13:
            age_category = "Child"
            print(f"{name} is a {age_category}.")
        elif age > 12 and age < 21:
            age_category = "Teen"
            print(f"{name} is a {age_category}.")
        elif age > 19 and age < 65:
            age_category = "Adult"
            print(f"{name} is an {age_category}.")
        elif age >= 65:
            age_category = "Senior"
            print(f"{name} is a {age_category}.")

age_category_function(age)

I don't know how to define the variable {name} to pull from my list of names.
I am using Jupyter Notebooks Python 310 and am a complete beginner to programming.

You're on the right track, but you can reduce things further.
One of the most useful things here would be to use a data structure... or more simply put, a grouping of related items. There are lost of containers which can be used to represent your relations, the basic ones being lists, tuples, and dicts.
For example, you could turn your data into a list of tuples.
person1_name = input("First person's name: ")
person1_age = int(input("First person's age: "))
person2_name = input("Second person's name: ")
person2_age = int(input("Second person's age: "))
person3_name = input("Third person's name: ")
person3_age = int(input("Third person's age: ")) 

people = [
    (person1_name, person1_age),
    (person2_name, person2_age),
    (person3_name, person3_age),
]

Now when referencing a person you can use this list, where each item in the list is a tuple of (name, age). Python has lots of helper functions for working on simple data structures like this.
For example, the sorted function allows you to organize a list based on its properties. The itemgetter function provides an easy way to declare what properties to consider when sorting items.
from operator import itemgetter

# sort values by index 1 in each tuple... the age!
people = sorted(people, key=itemgetter(1))

# Now that the data is sorted, the first item has the lowest age.
youngest_name, youngest_age = people[0]
print(f"{youngest_name} is the youngest, they are {youngest_age} years old")

# Now that the data is sorted, the last item has the largest age.
oldest_name, oldest_age = people[-1]
print(f"{oldest_name} is the oldest, they are {oldest_age} years old")

Rather than having age_category_function print a value, have it return the category to use. This will lead to less repetition, and allow you to call it in more contexts.
def get_age_category(age):
    if age < 13:
        return "Child"
    elif age < 20:
        return "Teen"
    elif age < 65:
        return "Adult"
    else:
        return "Senior"

Now you can call it like this:
for name, age in people:
    age_category = get_age_category(age)
    print(f"{name} is a {age_category}.")

Going back to constructing the initial list, you could once again use functions to reduce repetition:
def ask_input(title):
    name = input(f"{title} person's name: ")
    age = int(input(f"{title} person's age: "))
    return (name, age)

people = [
    ask_input("First"),
    ask_input("Second"),
    ask_input("Third"),
]

Going even further:
people = []
for title in ("First", "Second", "Third"):
    people.append(ask_input(title))

And further again with a list comprehension!:
people = [
    ask_input(title) 
    for title in ("First", "Second", "Third")
]

Hope this was helpful! Let me know if you need more explanation!

sorted() seems inefficient at large scales if you only want the youngest and oldest. Unless there's an optimization I didn't know about? Not that it matters for three items.

@Anerdw that's a fair point. Alternatively, op could write youngest_name, youngest_age = min(people, key=itemgetter(1))  and oldest_name, oldest_age = max(people, key=itemgetter(1)) respectively, which avoids the overhead of a full sort at the cost of two scans. This still goes to show how using Pythons primitive data structures allows you to operate on groupings of related items, while keeping the code concise/readable.

Future reading for OP would be time complexity and space complexity, but I would defer these topics until after they become comfortable with the basics!

Ignoring space / time complexity for this trivial task.
What's really important when acquiring user input is that you validate it as best as you can. In this case you need to ensure that the name is not an empty string and that the age is a valid integer.
So, you would write a single discrete function to do that. Everything else can be table-driven. What you don't want is "magic" numbers scattered throughout your code.
Then you can introduce loops to work with your constant data. Later, let's say you want to add a fourth input, all you would need to do is add an appropriate string to the people list. Nothing else would change in your code.
people = ["First", "Second", "Third"]
ar = {
    "a Teen": (13, 19),
    "an Adult": (20, 65),
    "a Senior": (66, float("inf"))
}

def get_name_and_age(person):
    while True:
        while not (name := input(f"{person} person's name: ")):
            pass
        age = input(f"{person} person's age: ")
        try:
            return name, int(age)
        except ValueError:
            print("That is not a valid age - try again")

db = [get_name_and_age(person) for person in people]

sdb = sorted(db, key=lambda i: i[1])

print(f"{sdb[0][0]} is the youngest")
print(f"{sdb[-1][0]} is the oldest")

for name, age in db:
    for k, (lo, hi) in ar.items():
        if lo <= age <= hi:
            print(f"{name} is {k}")
            break
    else:
        print(f"{name} is not in a valid age category")

